# Is NSAttributedString attributedString.string.utf16.count always equivalent to attributedString.length?

Tags: ios, swift

I notice there are several ways to construct `NSRange`

```
let range = NSRange(location: 0, length: attributedString.length)        
attributedString.addAttribute(..., range: range)
```

and

```
let range = NSRange(location: 0, length: attributedString.string.utf16.count)        
attributedString.addAttribute(..., range: range)
```

I was wondering, is `attributedString.length` always equivalent to `attributedString.string.utf16.count`?

So far, I can't find out any case when they are different.

Is there a situation when they are not?

Comment: Normally, `NSAttributedString` like `NSString` should use the UTF16 to count. I'm not sure about AttributedString though (for SwiftUI).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, they're the same. According to Apple's document  NSAttributedString.length is The number of UTF-16 code units in the receiver.

Then

attributedString.length = attributedString.string.utf16.count

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsattributedstring/1418432-length